# adobe air app freezes suddenly but debugger claims exit with status 0

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

My air program freezes after running for some time without any error. The app will freeze (non responsive) and the debugger will claim the program has terminated with status 0.

I don't know what could possibly lead to this unpredictable behaviour.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this happen only when debugging, or does it also happen when you've exported a release build and installed the app?

Comment: both, i first noticed in the release build, later then debugging to trace it.

Comment: do you have a swc included in your project that includes AIR classes?  If so, are you sure those air classes are the same as the flex/air sdk you're currently using?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable logging in your app, it isn't trivial though. But, I have had the same problem and for me it is because I am getting a stack overflow. Safari which is the browser in air has a substantially smaller call stack that other browsers, so this tends to happen.

Comment: just for clarity, WebKit is the rendering engine that AIR uses, which Safari also happens to use (as well as Chrome). Safari itself, is not used by Adobe AIR.

Comment: You're right but AIR uses the version of webkit that is present in safari 4 if I'm not mistaken. So, you can use that as a way to find what features are available to you.